# GROUP rows when conditions are met

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I hope you can help me out with the next problem. I am trying to figure out how to count many records exist when some conditions occur.

An example of my input is shown below:

```
fullname    emailaddress1   telephone1 
Juana Foster    juana   
Juana Foster    juana       1933595322
Henzley                     1841901633
Henzley         henzley     1841901633
Hoyle           hoyle       1584190699
Hoyle           hoyle       1584190655
Aaron Jeans     alpha2222   1816808600
Aaron Jeans     alpha       1816808600
Erick Martin    a1009       1816250211
Erick Martin    martin      1565960141
Erick Martin    a1009   
Erick Martin    martin      1565960141
```

I would like to group the occurrences which match the next conditions:
 `Fullname = Fullname and ((emailaddress = emailaddress and emailaddress != '') OR (telephone=telephone and telephone != ''))`. 
In other words, I want to group in one row, all the rows which have the same fullname and, same email or address. Email and Address must be distinct to empty to be considered matchable.

The expected output would be:

```
fullname     occurrences
Juana Foster  1
Henzley       1
Hoyle         1
Aaron Jeans   1
Erick Martin  2
```

I don't have any problem to solve the problem in a loop, but I have been thinking how to solve the problem in SQL, and tried GROUP BY and UNIONS, however and I haven't reached the solution. I am using mySQL.

**UPDATE:**
I provide a new example with more specific cases, in order to clarify the information:
For example for the next input
`fullname    emailaddress1   telephone1 
Aaron Jeans     alpha2222   1816808600
Aaron Jeans                 1816808600
Aaron Jeans     alpha2222   1816808600
Aaron Jeans     alpha       1816808600
Erick Martin    a1009       1816250211
Erick Martin    a1009 
Erick Martin                1816250211
Erick Martin    martin      1565960141

Erick Martin    martin      1565960141
Nacho Mason                 1111111111
Nacho Mason                 2222222222`

In this case the output should be:
`Aaron Jeans     1
 Erick Martin    2
 Nacho Mason     2`

Aaron Jeans has 1 occurrence because his 4 records share the same telephone.

Erick Martin has 2 occurrences, the first one is for the next cases:

`Erick Martin    a1009       1816250211
Erick Martin    a1009 
Erick Martin                1816250211`

Because the 3 records share same fullname and (same email(a1009) or same phone (1816250211), these three records are considered 1 occurrence.
The second occurrence for Erick Martin match with the next two records, because it has same fullname, same email and same phone.

`Erick Martin    martin      1565960141

Erick Martin    martin      1565960141`

Nacho Mason has 2 occurrences, because he has 2 different phones, and as his email is empty, and can't be considered equal.

Comment: let's see the `GROUP BY` statement that doesn't work, because the answer lies therein.

Comment: What do you mean by "next conditions"?  SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "next" condition, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: How would you count `('John', 'mail1', '111'), ('John', 'mail2', '111'), ('John', 'mail1', '222'), ('John', 'mail3', '222')`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're trying to do.
first you want to do a SELECT of all occurrences where Email is not blank and telephone is not blank like

```
SELECT fullname,emailaddress1,telephone1,COUNT(*) AS occurrences
  FROM T
  WHERE emailaddress1 != ''
    AND telephone1 != ''
  GROUP BY fullname,emailaddress1,telephone1
```

then now you outer SELECT and MAX(occurrences) GROUP BY fullname

```
SELECT fullname, MAX(occurrences) as occurrences
FROM
(SELECT fullname,emailaddress1,telephone1,COUNT(*) AS occurrences
  FROM T
  WHERE emailaddress1 != ''
    AND telephone1 != ''
  GROUP BY fullname,emailaddress1,telephone1
)AS result
GROUP BY fullname
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f78404/4)
At least, I think that's what you're trying to get at.

curious though, what if you had another full name with 3 rows of identical email and phone number and the same full name with another 2 rows of identical email and phone number like this

```
Adam Smith   adam  1234
Adam Smith   adam  1234
Adam Smith   adam  1234
Adam Smith   smith 5678
Adam Smith   smith 5678
```

Do you want to show as Adam Smith 3 or Adam Smith 2 or both?
the query above will you Adam Smith 3

**UPDATE:** I guess based on your desired output you want Adam Smith 3 because with your Erick Martin 2, he would've had Erick Martin 1, Erick Martin 2 from the inner select.

Comment: The answer is close to the solution, however it does not work for some specific cases.